# Last 7 days from postgres table epoch timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have a table (funny_quotes) which has a column called quote_date and it stores data in unix epoch time (seconds)

I want to run a query to only return data from this table(funny_quotes) only from the last 3 days.

I created a table locally in postgres but unable to store dates as epoch time, they only get stored as timestamp values

select * from funny_quotes where quote_date > (now() - interval '3 days')

Comment: 3 or 7 days? Show the table definition, please.

Comment: @fphilipe - 3 days, Its a simple table with 2 columns only one called quote of type varchar, and quote_date of type bigint

Comment: Do you have legacy code to maintain using the epoch? If not why opt for it when Postgres has extensive functionality for processing timestamps.  Unix epoch time is great for shell scripts but not otherwise. If you must maintain legacy code considering adding  a timestamp column (yea keeping in sync is a pain), but when version 12 arrives (now in beta 2) that can be changed to a 'generated column'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should modify the right side of the equation to epoch in order to be able to compare:

```
select * from funny_quotes where quote_date > extract(epoch from (now() - interval '3 days'))
```

Or the other way around: convert `quote_date` into timestamp:

```
select * from funny_quotes where to_timestamp(quote_date) > now() - interval '3 days'
```

You can read more about it [in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-datetime.html)